# VBA: If cell format is date then do something

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

I have a problem setting conditions for a macro.
It should do:

`If CELL_A is * **AND** CELL_B is **DATE** then....`

```
    Sub kontrolafyzprav()

radek = 4

  With List1

    Do While .Cells(radek, 3) <> ""
        If .Cells(radek, 3) = "DOM" And .Cells(radek, 7).NumberFormat = "General" Then
            .Cells(radek, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)
            .Cells(radek, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)

        ElseIf .Cells(radek, 3) = "MO" And .Cells(radek, 7).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy" Then
            .Cells(radek, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)
            .Cells(radek, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)
                    ' :(    :(     :(     :(

        End If
                radek = radek + 1
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

In the line with `ElseIf .Cells(radek, 3) = "MO" And .Cells(radek, 7).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy" Then` i tried like everything I could think of.

The first set of conditions works great but I can't get the second one :/

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the programme to find out why the second set of condition ws not working? What is wrong with your code? Are you sure that `Cells(radek, 7)` format is set to `d/m/yyyy` ?

Comment: @MaciejLos Iam sure as much as I can that it is in d/m/yyyy. Anyway it has been aswered below and it works just fine. Dont ask me how o.O

Comment: I see the answer, but have you seen my comment to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native VBA [IsDate Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278584.aspx) makes a good determination of a cell's contents to see if it contains a date or not. Regional date-specific settings that are retained by the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) (but not the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx)) help make the determination.

```
Sub kontrolafyzprav()
    Dim raek As Long

    radek = 4

    With List1
        Do While .Cells(radek, 3) <> ""
            If .Cells(radek, 3) = "DOM" And .Cells(radek, 7).NumberFormat = "General" Then
                .Cells(radek, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)
                .Cells(radek, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)

            ElseIf .Cells(radek, 3) = "MO" And IsDate(.Cells(radek, 7)) Then
                .Cells(radek, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)
                .Cells(radek, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 150)
                        ' :(    :(     :(     :(
            End If
            radek = radek + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

The IsDate function will not be fooled by an invalid text-that-looks-like-a-date.

Comment: I canaccept an answer in 4 minutes... but i surely want to do it now :D
Many thanks, this works great!

Comment: There's few known issues with `IsDate` function. For example it may return true for this statement: `13:28`. Assuming that user want to validate proper input, `IsDate` function probably isn't what OP is looking for...

Comment: @MaciejLos in this case the csv that serves as the source would never contain a time (13:28) so in this solution is pretty good.

Comment: @loqan, OK. If it meets your criteria, i'm going to upvote Jeeped's answer ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos Thanks, I got your point that it may not be the answer for every case but yea, it could save someone else's nerves :)